# Is there a Lie type algebra on the Leech lattice?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, integer-lattices

Lattices such as the $E_8$ lattice can be made into a Lie Algbera.

The $E_8$ lattice is the densest packing of spheres in 8D.
In 24D this is the Leech lattice $\Lambda_{24}$.

Is there any kind of algebra associated with the Leech Lattice (even if it is not a Lie algebra?)

Comment: It's not the root lattice of anything, in that it has no roots.

Answer (score 0):

There is an vertex operator algebra of the Leech lattice, see for example this article [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.01281). For more information on how to construct vertex operator algebras using lattices, see [this MO-question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/64610/codes-lattices-vertex-operator-algebras).